# Add linebreaks to XML layout template

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, code-templates

Is it possible to modify the XML layout template in Android Studio so that the namespace and attributes appear on separate lines?

#### Generated by default template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Preferred:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

The default template (below) shows each attribute (not including the namespace) on separate lines, but these line breaks don't translate to the generated resource file.

[image: Default layout resource template]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Android Studio isn't respecting line breaks in the XML templates.

#### Solution

1. Enable `Keep line breaks` in

   > Settings > Editor > Code Style > XML > Other (tab)
2. Add a line break before the namespace in the relevant (see Notes) code template(s) in

   > Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates > Other (tab)

#### Result

XML layouts will now generate the namespace and attributes on separate lines, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Notes

- The relevant code templates are:

  ```
  layoutResourceFile.xml
  layoutResourceFile_vertical.xml
  ```
- To ensure that `Keep line breaks` persists on subsequent runs of
  Android Studio, make sure to modify the `Project` scheme rather than
  the `Default` scheme.